# About Joomla install.eventlist.php

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I can't find any documentation for this file (install.eventlist.php). I'm already using it on my extensions to do database modification when for example my extension gets an update and needs some database table altering, but I don't think I'm using 100% its functionality. Is there any tutorial/article/documentation out there that focuses on this?

Already searched, but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to trigger any custom modification when a component is installed , updated  look at this link 
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file